# DevDays and the Fanatic badge

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2009, activity-badges

Don't be dumb like me and be sure to hit Stack Overflow with your phone or laptop sometime during the day so you don't reset your "fanatic" timer.

Comment: Are you sure you missed it? Has a mod confirmed it?

Comment: I'm almost positive, I don't really want to bother moderators about this kind of stuff.

Comment: Take it easy, dude!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm fully expecting to be posting answers during DevDays... at least occasionally.

I promise not to do so during my own talk though.

(I should try to remember how the outside world tends to treat presentations, actually. During Google Tech Talks it's entirely expected for a large proportion of the room to have a laptop open, checking mail, doing code reviews, etc. while people are talking. That doesn't tend to go down so well elsewhere.)

Comment: A part of your talk should be you answering on SO.

Comment: @Ólafur Just a part?  I'd say his whole talk should be him answering questions, and thinking out loud.  I bet he'd pack the room!

Answer (score 10):

Ok, I promise I won't be as dumb as you.

Comment: haha, it's not hard. +1 for being smarter than me